# "CREATE TABLE" instruction on multiple lines

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark-sql, rdbms

I have a code that works fine, but that is not very nice:

```
CREATE TABLE `/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very/very long path/output` AS
    SELECT 
        val1,
        val2,
        val3
    FROM `/small path/input`
    WHERE 
        conditions
```

I'd like to put the CREATE TABLE instruction on several lines properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Please Tag DBMS you are using, `create` table definition and `select` are you sure ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure! I just anonymized the names, but that is exactly my query.

Comment: Syntax error. Remove `,` after the last select list item.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I removed some item for the post and forgot this. I'll edit the post. But that's not really the point here.